# Drop Down menu leaves lines on the background after sliding up

Tags: drop-down-menu

I made a drop down menu and it works perfectly, but when the items slide up it leaves some horizontal lines behind, like a trace...is there a way to get rid of that??
thanks!
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
        <!-- Biscoitos -->
            <li><aside id="biscoitos" onClick="Slider(this.id)">Biscoitos</aside>
                <ul>
                    <li><aside id="bisc-festas" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Festas</aside></li>
                    <li><aside id="bisc-mater" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Maternidade</aside></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!-- Chocolates -->
            <li><aside id="chocolates" onClick="Slider(this.id)">Chocolates</aside>
                <ul>
                    <li><aside id="choc-pascoa" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Páscoa</aside></li>
                    <li><aside id="choc-namo" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Dia dos Namorados</aside></li>
                    <li><aside id="choc-natal" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Natal</aside></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!-- Bolos -->
            <li><aside id="bolos" onClick="Slider(this.id)">Bolos</aside>
                <ul>
                    <li><aside id="bolo-aniver" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Aniversário</aside></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!-- Trufas -->
            <li><aside id="trufas" onClick="Slider(this.id)">Trufas</aside>
                <ul>
                    <li><aside id="trufa-aniver" onClick="Slider(this.id)">&#160&#160&#160Aniversário</aside>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#drop
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:5px 200px;
    padding:0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#drop li:hover
{
    background:url("/img/menu7.png");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:180px 30px;  
}

#drop li
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:180px;
    /*background-color:#888a85;*/
    background:url("/img/menu8.png");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:180px 30px;
    margin:0px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    padding:6px;

}
#drop li ul 
{
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    width:180px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    margin:1px 0px 1px -6px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1; 
    padding:6px;
}
#drop ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    padding:6px;
    margin:1px 0px 1px -6px;
}
```

JS

```
// Drop Down Menu
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        $("#drop li").hover( 
        function()
        {
            $("ul", this).stop(true, true).slideDown(800);
        },
        function()
        {
            $("ul", this).stop(true, true).slideUp(800);
        });

    });
```

Sorry about the lack of information..Many thanks!

Comment: That's only for Google Chrome, Mozilla is perfect.

Comment: Hi! it's a simple ul drop down menu, animated with jquery hover(). I got it from this site:

http://www.queness.com/post/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in Chrome, I've been working to try and solve it for a site I'm doing as well.

It appears that the last (bottom) 1-pixel-wide strip on the receding div is not re-drawn sometimes (and not always the same place or number of missed re-draws) - so my workaround is to give the sliding div a 1px solid border the same colour as the background - so if and when it leaves the line while receding its barely noticable.

Hope that helps - its not a solution, but I'm pretty sure from the research I've done that the slideUp/slideDown code is fine, its a browser bug... so this is probably as close to fixing it as you will get until Chrome is fixed.